# Removing elements from a dictionary consisting of tuples calculating the last element in the tuple and the value in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

The following dictionary is given:

```
a = {('a','b', 'c'):3,('a','d','c'):4, ('f','e','b'):5, ('r','t','b'):5.1}
```

The dictionary consists of tupels as a key and numbers as a value. Each tuple consists of a series of letters.
From  all the tuples whose last element is the same one should exclude those whose dictionary value is the lowest.
For example the tuple `('a','b', 'c')` and the tuple `('a','d','c')` Both have the letter `C` as the last element, therefore the one whose value is the lowest should be removed.
With reference to the above dictionary the result should be:

```
{('a','d','c'):4, ('r','t','b'):5.1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

a = {('a','b', 'c'):3,('a','d','c'):4, ('f','e','b'):5, ('r','t','b'):5.1}

# group the items by the last element of the key of the tuple
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in a.items():
    lookup[key[2]].append((key, value))

# find the maximum in each group by the value of the tuple
result = dict(max(value, key=itemgetter(1)) for value in lookup.values())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{('a', 'd', 'c'): 4, ('r', 't', 'b'): 5.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
a = {('a','b', 'c'):3,('a','d','c'):4, ('f','e','b'):5, ('r','t','b'):5.1}

keys_to_remove = []
for key in a.keys():
    srch_key = key[-1]
    lowest_val = min(v for k,v in a.items() if k[-1] == srch_key)
    keys_to_remove.append(*(k for k,v in a.items() if k[-1] == srch_key and v == lowest_val))
    
for key_to_remove in set(keys_to_remove):
    a.pop(key_to_remove)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'd', 'c'): 4, ('r', 't', 'b'): 5.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be:

```
a_dict = {('a','b', 'c'):3,('a','d','c'):4, ('f','e','b'):5, ('r','t','b'):5.1}


b_dict = dict()
seq = 2
for key in a_dict:
    b_key = find_key(b_dict, key[seq])
    if b_key is not None:
        b_dict.pop(b_key)
        b_dict[key] = a_dict[key]
    else:
        b_dict[key] = a_dict[key]


def find_key(x_dict, k, seq=2):
    for key in x_dict:
        if key[seq] == k:
            return key
    return None
```

Create an empty dictionary. Iterate over the dict, search the last element of the key tuple in new dict. Add the key:value to new dict if not exists.
If found any, check if its value is greater or not. If it is not, delete the element and add the new key:value.